# PrimeNG removed styles after upgrade to version 13

Tags: angular, primeng

In my company, we upgraded our angular and primeng to version 13. The following styles are removed:

- ui-state-default    ui-state-hover  ui-state-active  ui-corner-all
  ui-widget-header  ui-widget-content

But we used them in our application.

Should we replace them? Or we have to adjust our css class?

Thank you, very much!

Answer (score 3):

you could try and replace them.Based on this [commit](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/c5f3d87e39b6d5f01ca3ffc0ab9af5062bc4e402#diff-a87ef8e07858b812d2f58a0deb22658db3c77c0d7d1b09a0e7b5667a88bac9d7L41) for example
`ui-state-active` becomes `p-highlight`. Better approach will be to use custom external classes and don't relay on primeng classes as much as you can. tabmenu has `styleClass` property which can be used